# Excel wildcards not finding the matches they should in VLOOKUP function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, wildcards, microsoft-excel-365

I have multiple product families I'm working with, and each family has multiple products within.  Some families have more products than others, all product names are unique. On one sheet named "prod fams", I have a lookup table like this:

```
| Product names                   | Product family |
|:----                            |:------:        |
| Prod1, Prod2                    | Gizmos         |
| Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4  | Widgets        |
```

In another sheet I have a database of field failures. Each row is a failure instance and has a product associated with it like this:

```
| Case number | Date   | Product Name |
|:----        |:------:|:------:      |
| 1           | 2/21/22| Prod2        |
| 2           | 2/22/22| Thing3       |
```

I want to add a fourth column to this database for Product Family.  My formula is a Vlookup like so:

`=VLOOKUP("*"& C2 &"*",'prod fams'!A$1:B$12,2,FALSE)`

So I find *Prod2* (in this case) in the Product Names column in the look-up table - note the asterisk wildcards - and return the Product Family.  This works for "Gizmos" not for "Widgets." For Widgets, I get #N/A.  What is going on here?

Comment: For what it's worth, the second table's formatting shows up fine in the preview, then comes out here looking like a dumpster fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently, Excel wildcards can only search a certain number of characters. My work-around was to make another row in the lookup table for "Widgets" and put half the products in the first row and the rest in the second.

I'm not certain what that character limit is, but i suspect it's 255.  The reason being that the rows I had to split up were ~280 characters (and 255 is a max-value byte in decimal).

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `wildcard` aspect. `VLOOKUP()` itself can only use the first 255 characters.

(There are ways to handle that, but that isn't the point here.)

`INDEX/MATCH` has the same problem.

However, the simplest solution is to use `XMATCH()` instead (as a much newer function, it is able to handle longer strings).

That would allow you to keep your original structure, if that is important to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).